# Eclipse DLTK при отладке TCL не выводятся сообщения в консоль

Tags: eclipse, консоль, tcl

В стандартную консоль Eclipse сообщения от TCL команд, например: puts "something" не показываются в режиме debug, но показываются при запуске Relise.
В чем может быть проблема?

Пробовал на Eclipse Neon и Luna. Самое интересное, что стандартная консоль пропадает и при запуске debug и вместо нее появляется консоль  для ввода TCL команд (не интерактивная, а именно TCL). Простую консоль в списке доступных нет. Пробовал debuger TCL от komodo 9 и 10, в обоих проявляется всё одинаково.
[image: При Debug режиме не выводятся сообщения от puts в консоль]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась после установки Eclipse C/C++Developers (CDT). В CDT также устанавливается плагин DLTK и дебагер.